# Why I am getting "no-undef " error when I run react js component class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new to react js. I have created a class extends Component. When I run my code it throws error mentioned that, variables are not defined. I am following a tutorial. This is works for the tutor correctly. But I am getting error.

**App.js**

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';
import TextCard from './textCard';


class App extends React.Component {

 
  
  textArr = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name:"Name1",
      department:"Computer",
      semester :7,
    },
    {
      id:2,
      name: "Name2",
      department: "Computer",
      semester: 7,
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Name3",
      department: "Computer",
      semester: 7,
    }
  ]

  

  textCards = this.textArr.map((item)=>{
    return (
      <TextCard  key={item.id} name={item.name} department={item.department} semester={item.semester} />
     )
  })

  hideOnClick(){
    alert('Hide btn pressed')
  }

  text1 = "Testing variable access"

  render(){
    return(
      <div className="App">
        <h1>My React js</h1>
        <h2>React js course from Udemy</h2>
        <hr></hr>
        <h3>JSX test</h3>
        <hr></hr>
        <div>{this.text1}</div>
        <hr></hr>
        <button onClick={this.hideOnClick}>Hide List</button>
        <div>
          {this.textCards}
        </div>
    </div>
    );
  }
 
}

export default App;
```

**textCard.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import classess from './textCard.module.css';

const TextCard = (props) =>{
    return(
        <div className={classess.dynamicTest}>
            <h2>{props.name}</h2>
            <p>{props.department}</p>
            <p>{props.semester}</p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default TextCard;
```

**The Error**

Failed to compile.

src\App.js
Line 11:3:  'textArr' is not defined    no-undef
Line 34:3:  'textCards' is not defined  no-undef
Line 50:3:  'text1' is not defined      no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Comment: Your map function is riddled with errors so I would try to fix that first.

Comment: Typo, missing closing `)` in your mapping, and `this.item` should be just `item`. https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-cookies-dkz2g?file=/src/App.js:111-178 Be aware that there is a very recent issue with new projects created with `create-react-app` with class-based components having issues with `this` bindings. You can search the issues in their Github, it's hard to miss.

Comment: @codemonkey React version is 17.0.1

Comment: @DrewReese If i change the version will it be fine? or is there any other ways to solve this issue? I have checked your link also

Comment: Fix your map function first. Change `key={this.item.id} name={this.item.name}...` to `key={item.id} name={item.name}...`

Comment: Probably not, since React version is completely unrelated to create-react-app version, that is, if my guess was correct that this is a new project created using CRA. Or are you talking about CRA version? Did you examine the code in the working codesandbox I linked? It's a copy/paste of your code, with fixes applied.

Comment: @DrewReese Yes. I checked it and it was worked on codesandbox. But not working in my PC

Comment: @codemonkey I changed it. Then also same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install and use the [@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties) to use [class fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields). Class fields are not in the Javascript core language yet and you need to tell the Babel compiler how to handle them if you want to use them.

```sh
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties
```

And add this to your `.babelrc.json`

```json
 "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
```

If your tutorial didn't mention that you need to install this plugin, it is not a good tutorial.